# Understand the $.support in modal.js

Tags: jquery

Hey guys i was going though a plugin code and came across the following lines of code :

```
 $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
      this.$element
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(this.hideModal, this))
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
      this.hideModal().
```

I am new to Jquery and really need help understanding the below line from the above snippet of code :

```
 $.support.transition
```

what is that line doing? i understand the short circuiting part , but what eactly is that line doing ?

the best i could do is refer the jquery doc's and get the below :

> Jquery.support :
>
> A collection of properties that represent the presence of different
>   browser 
>         features or bugs. Intended for jQuery's internal use; specific properties may be 
>         removed when they are no longer needed internally to improve page startup performance. 
>         For your own project's feature-detection needs, we strongly recommend the use of an external 
>         library such as Modernizr instead of dependency on properties in jQuery.support.

but somehow , i am not able to link the usage of $.support to what the documenattion is saying .

can somebody please explain ? .

Comment: explain what specifically? We don't know what it is you don't understand

Comment: @charlietfl , what is this line doing `$.support.transition` ?

Comment: checking for transition event support in browser

Comment: @charlietfl i can't find any Jquery doc's for this Jquery Function ? anything on the WWW , that can be more elaborate that your one-liner , would be appreciated . Thanks .

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition